# How do I join these tables when the first join needs to account for a NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
TableA      TableB                         TableC

matl        matl |   job  |   suffix       job  |  suffix
-------     ----------------------------   --------------
itemA       itemA|   jobA |  suffixA       jobA  |  suffixA
itemB       NULL |   NULL |   NULL
```

--

After joining, I need to return:

Query

```
matl  |    job    suffix
---------------------------
itemA |    jobA   suffixA
itemB |    NULL   NULL
```

How would I write my query to use the information in `TableA` to return information from `TableC`, and return `NULL` if there is no information in `TableC` after joining?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.matl,
       B.jobA,
       B.suffix
  FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT *
           FROM TableB 
          WHERE ( job,suffix ) IN ( SELECT job,suffix FROM TableC ) 
       ) B
    ON A.matl = B.matl;
```

Comment: Please see the last paragraph of the question - I need to return information from `TableC`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.matl = B.matl
LEFT JOIN TableC C
ON B.job = C.job
AND B.suffix = C.suffix
```